# Swift 2 Callback after async execution

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swift2, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to get JSON from a service in Swift 2

```
https://someapidomain.com/entries.json 
[
1212,
1234,
2934,
....
]

https://someapidomain.com/entry/entry_id.json 
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": 23,
  "key3": "value3,
   ...
}

Service must return:
[
 {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": 23,
  "key3": "value3,
   ...
},
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": 23,
  "key3": "value3,
   ...
},
....
]


struct ExampleService {

private static let baseURL = "https://someapidomain.com/"
private static let entries_per_page = 10

private static func getJSONResponse(url: String, callback: (AnyObject) -> () ){

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
            data, response, err -> Void in

            do {
                let jsonResponse = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
                callback(jsonResponse)

            }catch {
                print("Error processing json")
            }

        })
        task.resume()


    }

 static func getEntries(url: String, callback: ([[String: AnyObject]]) -> ()) {

        var entries: [[String:AnyObject]] = []
        let apiURL = baseURL + url

        getJSONResponse(apiUrl) { (response) in
            if let entryIds = response as? Array<Int> {
                for entryId in storyIds[0..<entries_per_page] {
                    let entryURL = baseURL + "/entry/\(entryId).json"

                    getJSONResponse(entryURL) { (response) in

                        if let entry = response as? [String: AnyObject] {

                           print(entry)
                           entries.append(entry)

                        }

                    }

                }

               callback(entries)

            }
        }


    }

}


}
```

Now when I call the service I get empty array

```
ExampleService.getEntries("/entries.json") { (response) in
     print(response)  // prints []
}
```

Whereas individual entries inside the loop prints the json. I think its because the callback is getting called before the for loop excecution is finished.

How can I fix this?

Comment: In getEntries(), you add the base URL to entryURL but not to the request to get Entry ID's.

Comment: @PriceRingo corrected. Thanks!

Comment: @rashwan-l Please stop adding the `ios` tag to questions that are not *directly* related to iOS and could work for other Swift supporting platforms. Thank you.

Comment: @EricD. I´ll keep that in mind, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modified function `getEntries` sketches how you can accomplish this with a dispatch_group.

Additionally, you MUST ensure your function `getJSONResponse` always calls the completion handler, even in the case it fails. This is because, you must ensure the function calls `dispatch_enter` and `dispatch_leave` are balanced.

I would recommend to modify the `getEntries` function as well in that sense, that is always call the completion handler even when it fails. Modify the signature of the completion handler accordingly.

```
static func getEntries(url: String, callback: ([[String: AnyObject]]) -> ()) {

    var entries: [[String:AnyObject]] = []

    getJSONResponse(url) { (response) in
        let queue = dispatch_queue_create("myqueue", nil)
        let group = dispatch_group_create()
        if let entryIds = response as? Array<Int> {
            for entryId in entryIds {
                dispatch_group_enter(group)
                let entryURL = baseURL + "/entry/\(entryId).json"
                getJSONResponse(entryURL) { (response) in
                    if let entry = response as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        print(entry)
                        entries.append(entry)
                    }
                    dispatch_group_leave(group)
                }
            }
        }
        dispatch_group_notify(group, queue) {
            callback(entries)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/)

Example below to create, enter and leave

```
let jsonGroup = dispatch_group_create()

    for x in json{
        dispatch_group_enter(getDeparturesGroup)

        // Some code...
    }

    dispatch_group_wait(jsonGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```